# about my page validation or verification

Tags: php

this is my code:  is it possible to make

```
if(isset($_GET['home'])){
if($_SESSION['valid_user']==null){
    $_SESSION['pages']=0;//this is when user is not login or visitor
}else{
    if($_SESSION['valid_admin']==1){
        $_SESSION['pages']=1;//this is when user is login as admin
    }else{
        $_SESSION['pages']=2;//this is where user is login
    }
}
}
```

when i make my code like this.

```
 if(isset($_GET['home'])){
if($_SESSION['valid_user']==null){
    $_SESSION['pages']=0;//this is when user is not login or visitor
}else{
    if($_SESSION['valid_admin']==null){
        $_SESSION['pages']=0;//this is when user is login as admin
    }else{
        $_SESSION['pages']=2;//this is where user is login
    }
}
}
```

where should i put the code for if the valid_admin or admin_user is login i created 3 different pages for my home page.. 1=for user 1=for admin and 1=for visitor sorry for my bad english im am just and newbie in php...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['home'])){
  if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {
    $_SESSION['pages']=0;//this is when user is not login
  } else {
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid_admin'])) {
      $_SESSION['pages']=1;//this is when user is login as admin
    } else {
      $_SESSION['pages']=2;//this is where user is login or Visitor
    }
  }
}
```

and in that case you only set the according `$_SESSION` member.

Comment: $_SESSION['pages']=2;//this is where user is login..... yeah i only set according to $_SESSION member.

Comment: I meant in the login process you only set that one array item in $_SESSION, which gives the actual user's access level, as here you only check them being set (regardless of the value). For a user you set $_SESSION['valid_user'], and for an admin only $_SESSION['valid_admin'].